# How can i define dynamically a constant inside dynamically defined subclass of dynamically defined class

Tags: ruby

How can i define dynamically a constant inside dynamically defined subclass of dynamically defined class, like this, but without `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar` error:

```
Object.const_set('Foo',Class.new) {|klass| klass.const_set('Bar', Class.new){|subklass| subklass.const_set(:YEP,'Yep!')}}
```

to get:

```
> Foo::Bar::YEP #=> 'Yep!'
```

Comment: To add on to the answer by Simple Lime ... any method can be called with a block, however it may not actually _run_ the block. For example, `Object.const_set("Foo", 1) { |x| puts x.class }` prints nothing, since `const_set` doesn't call the block passed to it. `Class.new`, on the other hand, does call the block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you wrap method parameters in parenthesis, the curly brace block gets applied to the method call, not the last parameter in the list. So those `{ |klass| ... }` are being passed to `Object.const_set` not to `Class.new`. If you move that close parenthesis after the block it'll work because the blocks get passed to `Class.new` instead of `Object.const_set`:

```
Object.const_set('Foo',Class.new { |klass|
  klass.const_set('Bar', Class.new { |subklass|
    subklass.const_set(:YEP,'Yep!')
  })
})
Foo::Bar::YEP # => "Yep!"
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is equivalent to @SimpleLime's answer, just expressed differently.

```
def make_class(name, parent=Object)
  Object.const_set(name, Class.new(parent))
end

foo = make_class('Foo')
  #=> Foo
bar = make_class('Bar', foo)
  #=> Bar
bar.superclass
  #=> Foo
bar.const_set('YEP', 'Yep!')
Bar::YEP
  #=> "Yep!"
bar::YEP
  #=> "Yep!"
```

If desired, the variables could be factored out.

```
make_class('Bar', make_class('Foo')).const_set('YEP', 'Yep!')
Bar::YEP
  # => "Yep!"
```

See [Class::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Class.html#method-c-new) and [Module#const_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set)

Classes created dynamically are often used anonymously (nameless), in which case one would simply write:

```
foo = Class.new
bar = Class.new(foo)
bar.const_set('YEP', 'Yep!')
bar::YEP
  #=> "Yep!"
```

and reference the classes by the variables `foo` and `bar`.